# Installing QGIS with GRASS access?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation, windows, qgis-2.12

I am working wit a win10 64 bits 16mb of ram. I want to install Lyon on my computer and not get rid of 2.83. My 2.83 is a stand allone install. I thought I could install Lyon usion OSGEO 4w installer. Nevertheless, even though I tried several times, I can not get acces to the grass plugin. I can not found it on the plugin manager nor I can found a toolbar. I tried to uninstall the OSgeo4w install several times, ask for to isntall Lyon, grass and Saga and no luck at all. I found at http://mappinggis.com/2015/08/novedades-del-plugin-grass-en-qgis-2-10-pisa/ (in spanish) that Lyon handles grass differently than 2.83 and that in order to have access to Grass I must install it using the stand allone version.

How do I a Install Lyon with Grass support using the OSGEO  installer and not the standalone?

Comment: Using the "express desktop install" option in the OSgeo4w installer does the trick. Now you have 2 installations of Qgis, one with acces to grass. The acces is a bit different but it does work. I was able to open an existing an existing map set open layers and work with them without a problem. Now it is just a matter of getting confortable with the new procedure.

Comment: You should post your comment as an **answer** :)

Comment: use emage condition of 2005 vanadhikar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have grass acces using the OSgeo4w installer in windows you must use the express desktop install option. The other two options do install Qgis but you will not have a grass plugin (at least in my experience). Once the installation is finished you will have in the OSgeo4w menu folder

Qgis browser

Qgis browser with Grass 6.43

Qgis Desktop 2.12.0

Qgis Desktop 2.12.0 with grass 6.43

If you want to work with Grass you have to choose Qgis Desktop 2.12.0 with grass 6.43
Once the program is open you must check in Plugins/manage and install plugins/installed that the grass6 plugin is present and that is checked for use.

[image]

Now open the browser panel and also Grass tools panel in View/panels/. In the browser panel navigate to your map set folder right click on it and choose "open map set".

[image]

Now you can add layers by double clicking on them. Once the map set folder is open and have some layers displayed you can work with Grass with the Grass Tools panel that we activated before.

[image]